# How to extract the values from the response body in postman

Tags: postman

After posting the request, API return response body as string

Response body look like

> { UniqueID = 93243434,birthGender = M,birthDate = 11/1/2018 5:51:18
>   PM,  familyNames = James, givenNames = Test }

when I try to set the environment variable using the below code

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("currentUniqueId", data.UniqueId);
```

I got the below error on test results

> Error message:
>   There was an error in evaluating the test script:  JSONError:
>   Unexpected token 'U' at 1:3 { UniqueID = 93243434,birthGender =
>   M,birthDate = 11/1/2018 5:51:18 PM, family ^

my goal is I need to extract the value 93243434 and assign to environment variable.

Comment: pm.globals.set("currentUniqueId",data.UniqueId);
or first you have to create the environment and use that in Tests.

Answer (score 16):

Hi you are using the correct way but you can try this version

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("UNIQUE_ID", jsonData.UniqueID);
```

The `set("UNIQUE_ID"` will help you save it in variable and you can name it as you want and `jsonData.uniqueID` will extract what you want to get from the Json response

If you view my approach I am extracting Access code and company id and saving it in variable and calling it in all next api's

Answer (score 2):

You are using a notation pattern that is deprecated.

Instead of set your variable using:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("currentUniqueId", data.UniqueId);
```

Try to set your variable this way:

```
pm.environment.set('currentUniqueId', pm.response.json().UniqueID);
```

To get more information, try: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_examples/